# OPCache can't be enable when configuring PHP 7.0.0RC5 on Raspbian

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, raspbian, opcache

I am running the latest version of Raspbian (Raspbian Jessie 2015-09-24) and I am trying to compile the latest RC of PHP 7 (PHP 7.0.0RC5). When configuring PHP, I can't get it to accept the parameter "--enable-opcache".

I have done all my tests on Debian Jessie 8.2.0 32-bit (in a virtual machine on my Windows PC) prior to moving to an actual Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. On Debian, the following configure is working no problem.

The problem I have on Raspbian is that `./configure` stops with the following error:

```
checking "whether flock struct is linux ordered"... "no"
checking "whether flock struct is BSD ordered"... "no"
configure: error: Don't know how to define struct flock on this system, set --enable-opcache=no
```

When disabling the OPCache with `--enable-opcache=no`, the configure complete with no error.

Here is the configure I am using:

```
CC="gcc-4.9" CXX="g++-4.9" CFLAGS="-I/usr/local/lib/libzip/include" CXXFLAGS="-I/usr/local/lib/libzip/include" ./configure \
--disable-flatfile \
--disable-inifile \
--enable-calendar \
--enable-exif \
--enable-fpm \
--enable-gd-jis-conv \
--enable-gd-native-ttf \
--enable-intl \
--enable-mbstring \
--enable-zip \
--with-bz2 \
--with-curl=/usr/local \
--with-freetype-dir=/usr/local \
--with-gd \
--with-icu-dir=/usr \
--with-jpeg-dir \
--with-libmbfl \
--with-libxml-dir \
--with-libzip=/usr/local \
--with-mcrypt \
--with-mysqli=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config \
--with-openssl \
--with-pcre-dir=/usr/local \
--with-pcre-regex=/usr/local \
--with-pdo-mysql=/usr/local/mysql \
--with-png-dir=/usr/local \
--with-webp-dir \
--with-xpm-dir \
--with-xsl \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local \
--with-zlib-dir=/usr/local \
--with-zlib=/usr/local \
--without-cdb \
--without-pdo-sqlite \
--without-pear \
--without-sqlite3
```

Any idea on how I could enable OPCache for PHP on Raspbian?

Comment: have you installed libtool-ltdl-devel?

Comment: The package didn't exist on Raspbian, but I did found libltdl-dev. Installed it, re-did the configure, but it sill gives me the same error.

Comment: If I am reading things correctly, since you're not running `--disable-all`, you should be able to install OPcache post compile. *Once compiled, you can use the zend_extension configuration directive to load the OPcache extension into PHP. This can be done with zend_extension=/full/path/to/opcache.so on non-Windows platforms*

Comment: @Twisty, if the module compile fails pre-php-compile, it will still fail post-compile won't it?

Comment: @Wolfmah, I've had this problem before when building out servers. I didn't document which of the following specifically fixed this issue, but ensuring the following are installed should fix it for you: `libtool libtool-ltdl libtool-ltdl-devel libevent-devel libevent pcre-devel libxml2-devel autoconf gcc perl python flex make gdb bison gcc-c++ nc`

Comment: @RobGudgeon I was just going off the install instructions at php.net for OPcache.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but adding the new lib/packages didn't helped. Though I have dig around the configure script of PHP and found where it did the test for the flock struct. For the test, it compile a small bit of code and look for the result when executing it. I tried it manually, to see for myself, with the exact same gcc command line the script uses, and the generated executable is indeed failing to run with the following error: `error while loading shared libraries: libmysqlclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. I am looking into it right now.

Comment: that's pretty weird, can't see how libmysqlclient would be needed for flock. Do you have the following files somewhere on the system? `libltdl.dylib libltdl.a libltdl.7.dylib`? Keep us posted on what you find, I'd be interested to know :)

Comment: When doing a `ldd` on the compiled test of configure, all the libs are found, including ltdl, but couldn't found libmysqlclient.so.18. Though, when calling the compiler, there is the flag `-L/usr/local/mysql/lib` and when looking there, I can find the lib within that folder. It's just that gcc don't want to find it and I don't know why. What I did then, is create a symlink of libmysqlclient.so.18 inside /usr/lib. With that, my custom configure is now completing without problem and I can compile and install PHP.